# R, corrplot not blanking insig

Tags: r, p-value, r-corrplot

I am desperately trying to solve an issue with R corrplot. I have a small matrix that I would like to visualize using R and the `corrplot()` function. I am using the following script to produce my corrplot:

```
library(corrplot)
corr_rohdaten<-read.csv(file="path_only.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
M<-cor(corr_rohdaten)
cor.mtest <- function(mat, conf.level = 0.95) {
    mat <- as.matrix(mat)
    n <- ncol(mat)
    p.mat <- lowCI.mat <- uppCI.mat <- matrix(NA, n, n)
    diag(p.mat) <- 0
    diag(lowCI.mat) <- diag(uppCI.mat) <- 1
    for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
        for (j in (i + 1):n) {
            tmp <- cor.test(mat[, i], mat[, j], conf.level = conf.level)
            p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
            lowCI.mat[i, j] <- lowCI.mat[j, i] <- tmp$conf.int[1]
            uppCI.mat[i, j] <- uppCI.mat[j, i] <- tmp$conf.int[2]
        }
    }
    return(list(p.mat, lowCI.mat, uppCI.mat))
}

res1 <- cor.mtest(M, 0.95)
res2 <- cor.mtest(M, 0.99)
## specialized the insignificant value according to the significant level
##corrplot(M, p.mat = res1[[1]], sig.level = 0.2)
corrplot(M, p.mat = res1[[1]], insig = "blank", method="color", tl.col="black", type="lower", tl.cex=1.2)
```

The problem is now, that the corrplot shows a lot of insig fields that should according to spss and R be nonsigificant and be cleared out.

path_only.txt looks as the following:

```
MyoD9w  MyoD52w TNC9w   TNC52w  OxCI9w  OxCI52w OxCII9w OxCII52w    OxCIII9w    OxCIII52w   OxCV9w  OxCV52w Myogenin9w  Myogenin52w VEGF9w  VEGF52w COX4I29w    COX4I252w
0.6508  0.3862  0.0888  0.8239  1.3390  4.2471  2.7513  6.1901  4.9440  6.0180  1.1619  0.9240  2.0130  1.5483  1.0000  0.6016  0.7826  0.8244
0.1956  0.3954  0.1959  3.1073  1.3103  2.2127  0.9862  5.4116  1.7748  5.3906  0.7411  1.0165  2.1557  2.6942  1.1199  1.0128  1.4144  1.8681
0.6217  1.0000  0.4912  1.0000  0.4237  2.1208  0.7313  2.7154  0.5653  0.9250  0.9000  0.7145  4.8147  6.3509  1.2985  1.4768  2.2194  1.0000
```

My assumption is that something here is wrong with calculating or comparing the p-values or they get rounded.

Maybe for someone like you the mistake is visible within seconds. I spent hours on googling.

Another question that I would be interested to solve is: I would love to only show correlations with p<0.05 and r^2 > 0.7 resp. r^2 < 0.7. If that can be done within this graph I will ship over some beers to the first one solving this issue properly!

Comment: is the idea to look at the significance of the correlations between the correlations (not between the columns of path_only)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the significance of the correlation between columns in `corr_rohdaten`.  Here is a way to extract statistics from the `cor.test` function using `outer` to apply the test to the various combinations of columns.

```
## Define a function to operate on combinations of columns, 
## vectorized for arguments x and y so we can pass it to `outer`
f <- Vectorize(function(x, y, data, statistic, dim=1, ...) 
    cor.test(data[,x], data[,y], ...)[[statistic]][[dim]], vec=c("x", "y"))

## Wrap this in a another function to get the p.value and confidence intervals
myCorr <- function(data, conf.level=0.95) {
    pvals <- outer(names(data), names(data), f, 
                   data=data, statistic="p.value",          # additional arguments to f
                   conf.level=conf.level)                   # additional to cor.test
    lower <- outer(names(data), names(data), f, data=data, statistic="conf.int")
    upper <- outer(names(data), names(data), f, data=data, statistic="conf.int", dim=2)
    list(pvals=pvals, lower=lower, upper=upper)
}

## To recreate the plot you have, you would need to test the correlation between
## the columns of the correlation matrix, M.  I wasn't sure if this was what you wanted.
pvals2 <- outer(1:ncol(M), 1:ncol(M), f, data=M, statistic="p.value", conf.level=0.95)

## Make corrplot using p.values from test between columns of corr_rohdaten
## The upper and lower confidence intervals will be NULL because there are only
## 3 observations (conf.int requires at least 4)
stats <- myCorr(corr_rohdaten, conf.level = 0.95)

library(corrplot)
corrplot(M, p.mat = stats[["pvals"]], insig = "blank", method="color", tl.col="black", 
         type="lower", tl.cex=1.2, diag=F)
```

[image]

This isn't the most efficient way to do this.  It will rerun the correlation tests three times each, but I find it reasonably simple and `outer` is quite fast.

To fix your function to reproduce these results is quite simple.  Just pass it the `corr_rohdatem` instead of `M`, and add a check for enough observations before extracting `conf.int`.

```
cor.mtest <- function(mat, conf.level = 0.95) {
    mat <- as.matrix(mat)
    n <- ncol(mat)
    p.mat <- lowCI.mat <- uppCI.mat <- matrix(NA, n, n)
    diag(p.mat) <- 0
    diag(lowCI.mat) <- diag(uppCI.mat) <- 1
    for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
        for (j in (i + 1):n) {
            tmp <- cor.test(mat[, i], mat[, j], conf.level = conf.level)
            p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
            if (dim(mat)[1] > 3) {
                lowCI.mat[i, j] <- lowCI.mat[j, i] <- tmp$conf.int[1]
                uppCI.mat[i, j] <- uppCI.mat[j, i] <- tmp$conf.int[2]
            }
        }
    }
    list(p=p.mat, lower=lowCI.mat, upper=uppCI.mat)
}

res <- cor.mtest(corr_rhodaten)
corrplot(M, p.mat = res[["p"]], insig = "blank", method="color", tl.col="black", 
         type="lower", tl.cex=1.2, diag=F)
```